# Variance between gene probes in excel

Tags: excel

I have a list of gene expression under different treatments for 61,005 probes, corresponding to different genes.

Each column represents a different treatment. Each row is gene expression for each probe.

Here is an example of my data:

```
GENE_ID             McA     McB     McC     McD
GENE:JGI_V11_100009 769.83  726.97  737.75  949.81
GENE:JGI_V11_100009 248.65  275.62  250.64  249.04
GENE:JGI_V11_100036 2199.36 537.89  465     654.59
GENE:JGI_V11_100036 489.29  438.26  431.44  629.78
GENE:JGI_V11_100036 1498.15 1132.76 898.17  986.82
GENE:JGI_V11_100044 438.66  488.17  421.1   371.86
GENE:JGI_V11_100045 341.65  352.59  351.7   290.02
GENE:JGI_V11_100062 7178.42 7234.89 8614.36 1917.37
GENE:JGI_V11_100062 2476.8  2869.94 2090.16 2131.18
```

As you can see, some genes have multiple rows (for each different probe). Is there a way I can get the variance between the probes for each gene?

I cannot do it manually due to the large file.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? `SUMIFS()` or `AVERAGEIFS()`? Is there a specific formula you need to use for variance?

Comment: You say it is a large file but if you are able to open it in Excel, you should be able to use pivot tables. Put GENE_ID as the row and Var(McA),.. as the columns. If it is too large to open in Excel, you've got the wrong tags. Look at something very simple in a(n open-sourced) language such as R or Python.

Comment: Excel can do ANOVA (Analysis of Variance). You'll need to add the Analysis Toolpak Addin.

Comment: Variance between consecutive entries for the same probe or proper ANOVA?

Comment: Im trying to find the variance between consecutive entries for the same probe

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are going for more complex ANOVA but if simply looking at difference from prior observation for same probe, consider adding a helper column as shown in image which counts the number of occurences of the probe ID

e.g. in A2 and filled down is:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)
```

[image: Adding an ID to distinguish number of times a probe ID has appeared]

Then create a table out of your data with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

Then  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> + + <kbd>V</kbd> to create a pivottable from this table.

Arrange the pivottable as follows:

[image: Pivotlayout]

Then for each column in the pivtottable data area (i.e. sum of McA etc) - right click and Show Values As > Difference From (selected your desired view)

[image: Difference from]

I chose  Show Values As

Calculation: Difference From

Base Field: ID

Base Item: Previous

[image: Difference from previous value]

Result:

[image: Final layout]

As mentioned, you could choose a variety of different display methods.